# Aligned vs. Packed attributes

Tags: c, attributes, embedded, structure, memory-alignment

I am working on firmware for a 16-bit PIC and writing in C (Microchip C30 compiler). My device receives a long list of bytes from an external device, and then I am trying to copy those bytes into a structure. The structure is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) {
    char    F1Nickname[17];
    char    F2Nickname[17];
    DWORD   F1CurrentPos;
    DWORD   F2CurrentPos;
    WORD    F1CurrentTemp;
    WORD    F2CurrentTemp;
    DWORD   F1MaxPos;
    DWORD   F2MaxPos;
    BYTE    F1TempCompOn;
    BYTE    F2TempCompOn;
    BYTE    CheckSum;
} deviceStatus;
```

I was having a strange problem that whenever the total number of bytes in the structure was an odd number my program would freeze and get caught in AddressError service routine. I can fix the problem by simple adding an extra byte to the struct but that seems like a band-aid fix.

I put the packed attribute on the structure because I wanted to make sure the compiler didn't insert any filler bytes in between my variables. If that were to happen, the values in my structure would be incorrect when copied over from the received character array.

I know there is also an attribute called aligned. Does aligned just align the start of the structure to an even byte or does it align every item in the structure to an even byte? Do you think the aligned attribute is required here? If I add the aligned attribute to this structure, I should also add it to the structure on the device that is sending the data, right? As of now they are both defined the exact same way as shown above.

If I add the aligned attribute should I remove the packed attribute? Don't they basically do the opposite?

Comment: What is the microcontroller in question? dsPIC?

Comment: Align will align it on 16bit address boundary's.

Comment: I think your problem is that words and dwords need to be properly aligned (which they won't necessarily be when you have a packed structure). "The device architecture requires that words be aligned on even byte boundaries, so care must be taken when using the packed attribute to avoid runtime addressing errors." From [C30 C COMPILER USERS GUIDE](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/C30_Users_Guide_51284f.pdf)

Comment: If you have control over the sender as well as the receiver, can't you add padding to align all the fields properly? If they're the same architecture, you could even remove the `packed` attribute and let the compiler do the work.

Comment: Aligned is the opposite of packed.  Aligning is what causes padding bytes to be inserted.

Answer (score 2):

The `__attribute__` and `__packed__` are not part of the C standard and are extensions that your compiler is providing. The only way to know for sure what they mean is to look it up in the compiler documentation.

Comment: The idiom `__attribute__((__packed__))` seems to be a GCC idiom. One of the more ubiquitous compilers around, ISTM. Not standard, but not uncommon either.

Comment: @Rudy: True, a lot of PIC and microcontroller manufacturers use the GCC front end for their compilers.

Answer (score 2):

Certain microprocessor architecture can only do a data fetch on an address that is aligned to word boundaries and will throw an exception if they are not word aligned. Often the compiler will help out and generate code that performs the necessary acrobatics to ensure the fetches are word aligned but this does not seem to be the case with your compiler and that is why you are seeing the exceptions.

In your case, you are using a `struct` to serialize data and therefore it must be packed. In this case you must either rearrange your `struct` to ensure that there are no reads across word boundaries or you will need to use and unpacked struct and hand serialize the data.

Comment: actually, many architectures don't raise an exception at all, they just *do the wrong thing*, which could run the gamut of ignoring the least significant bit, converting the fetch in microcode into many byte fetch instructions (at significant performance cost), fetching only a portion of the word, or just entering an unknown state.

Comment: ISTM that if the platform needs alignment, hand serialization is indeed his only way out.